# Duplicate record crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

[image]

This is my report; when I use the formula

```
   IF {Customer.CustomerSay} = {?bank1} Then  ToNumber({Chc.CheckFe}) ELSE 0;
```

I get duplicate records.

For example I have 1 record 27 but when use that formula, it shows 6 records 27

[image]

When I use empty formula, there is no problem.

I think the formulation has a problem.

I want to use it like this :

When in record (bank) = with (bank 1) show sum just for bank 1 not other bank

Comment: Maybe you need to use brackets. See at the bottom of
[this](https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/crystal-reports-working-with-formulas.htm) article.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: Your formula doesn't create any problems, problem is, if I guess with the available data, there are multiple tables and when you use the field from customer table there is a linking happening at database level which is duplicating the data, check your linking